# How to close a program on a raspberry pi, in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

What code can be used to close a program running on RPI3?

I am running a 
[smart magic mirror](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkVBAcvbrjU) using my Raspberry Pi, and I want to then close it. How can I?

Comment: how would you close any python program? `return`, `break`, `sys.exit(0)`. If its another process, perhaps use `os.kill`

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you are accessing the Pi. If you are running it headless (without a separate monitor) then you need to use ssh to log in from another computer (`ssh username@ip-address` in the terminal window). You can then use other methods such as [process killing](https://superuser.com/questions/872244/killing-processes-in-raspbian) to force the program to stop running on the Pi.

Alternatively, if you have access to the where you started the program on your Pi (maybe a window, or a terminal window where the Pi is running your mirror program, then you could exit or use a common interrupt such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.